# UK: is up to 2 V AC between ground and neutral to be expected in a house supply?

Tags: mains, leakage-current

I am seeing around 2 V AC between ground and the neutral, circa 240 V AC to the live wire. Is this normal or does this indicate a weak ground or some leakage path between lines perhaps?

I have an issue with switching equipment throwing RCD breakers, and am wondering if some small leakage current exists that is pushing me close to trip limit.

Comment: What equipment are you switching?

Comment: A small industrial motor controller in a filtered enclosure.

Comment: I ask because some equipment has a capacitor between neutral and earth, probably for EMC reasons, and this will result in a small current differential that could trip an RCD if the vol between neutral and earth is significant.

Comment: The controller has a discrete filter installed on its supply. Knowing that ground is used for filtering would exactly explain why filters cause leakage to ground (in AC)

Comment: If you have a meter capable of measuring capacitance you might expect to see around 1 to 10nF if indeed there is a formal capacitor to earth.

Comment: That's a great idea, I've been measuring resistance and not finding much, capacitance tester would show it for sure. FYI is there such a thing as an impedance tester?

Comment: Probably the nearest thing is an LCR meter, measures inductance, capacitance and resistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be.

Most new supplies are TN-C-S (PME), where the earth and neutral are joined at the supply cut-out.  On those supplies, the voltage between the Main Earth Terminal and the Neutral at the consumer unit should be tiny.  But that may not still be true at the end of a long circuit, where there's a voltage drop along the neutral.

But many houses will still be on TN-S supplies, where the earth and neutral are only linked at the transformer.  There the voltage difference would be the voltage drop along the neutral, all the way back to the transformer.  A couple of volts wouldn't be at all surprising.

Some houses are also on TT supplies, where the only earth is a rod banged into the ground.  On these, you will again see the voltage drop along the whole neutral back to the transformer, and perhaps some other stray voltages as the transformer earth and your earth aren't well connected.

If you want to detect leakage currents, you need a sensitive clamp meter capable of measuring down to milliamps.  Either clamp it around an earth wire, or around the live and neutral simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is normal.  Single phase power is actually one phase from a 3-phase supply, and your local substation will be arranged so that there’s an approximately equal load on each phase.  In practice there will be slightly different loading and so the neutral wire will carry some net current (if perfectly balanced it would be zero).  Neutral is typically earthed at the substation and so what you’re seeing is the voltage drop in the neutral conductor.

Comment: This is untrue in the UK generally these days. The earth wire is bonded (normally) to the neutral wire inside the premises of the home. (reference TN-C-S system).

Comment: Any idea when that practice started?  My knowledge of UK practice is obviously out of date.  I know that US 110V systems ground locally but NZ doesn’t.

Comment: While TN-C-S is the most common system for new installations, there is still a heck of a lot of TN-S and TT out there.

Answer (score 1):

Neutral and ground (safety ground) are tied together at the panel or at the local feed, depending on the system in use. Normally, no current flows in the ground while return current flows in neutral, if there is a load on that branch.

That return current on neutral will cause an IR drop, which in turn causes a voltage difference to develop between it and ground. This is normal, as long as it's within limits set by your local (UK) electrical codes.

If there is *no* load on the branch, and you're still seeing significant ground-to-neutral voltage, there is a problem that could warrant investigation by an electrician, especially since you're seeing ground fault trips.

Comment: You are describing the American way of doing things. In the UK at least for domestic/small commercial installs (large commercial/industrial with private transformers may be another matter) Neutral and Earth are not interconnected on the customer's side. Depending on the installation they may be interconnected in the supplier's service head and share a conductor back to the supply transformer (TN-C-S system), they may be connected at the supply transformer (TN-S system) , or they may only be connected via the general mass of the earth (TT system).